# Android TV published app not visible in sony bravia android tv

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-tv, leanback

I have developed an app using `Leanback Library`. The app is working fine on `Sony Android TV`.

But when I have published the app successfully on `play store` then when i am searching app on my `Sony Android TV` store it is showing `No Results Found` message.

Here is `Manifest` of my TV app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"></uses-sdk>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/icon_new"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/ic_icon"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|stateVisible">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PlaybackOverlayActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".BrowseErrorActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MemoryVaultActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CustomFragment" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

On store only showing two supported devices.

1. Letv Max3-65
2. Letv Super TV X3-55 Pro

***My Question is***: What changes i need to made in my `Manifest` ? or any other suggestions to make it workable on `Sony Android TV`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What Android version is your bravia running? According to your manifest you should atleast run version 21.

Comment: @Doppie Yes the version running is 5.0. Please help me i can't be able to find out.

Comment: I think it must be the play store then, the only thing you "require" is the leanback library.. I would file an issue at google

Comment: @Doppie, please share URL once you filed the issue. I had the same issue.

Comment: @Doppie Yes please share the URL once you post an issue. and is their any required things i am forgetting to add in manifest for this issue?

Comment: Did you get your approval? See: https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/tv.html

Comment: @jaydroider, I said "I would", as in an advice that you could file an issue at Google ;)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for your reply i have checked on store and it is currently showing  `This application is being reviewed for approval`. But only showing `2 supported devices` which i mentioned in Question.

Comment: I'm guessing that the two devices are so new that the Google team hasn't enabled the gating per distribution link I provided or they aren't legal Google TV devices (a quick search on the model numbers shows a complaint on forum: http://forum.le.com/us/index.php?threads/letv-max3-65.600/)

Comment: @MorrisonChang But i have `Sony Android TV` and device related to this is not showing at all in supported devices on store.

Comment: But you aren't approved yet. The Google TV part is reviewed. If your app isn't approved I would not expect to be seen by a Google TV device. From the linked document: `If your app meet TV App Quality criteria, Google Play makes that app available to Android TV users.`

Comment: @MorrisonChang So i need to wait for status to be Approved or Pending on store to available app to `Android TV` users because while i am searching on web the app is showing published.

Comment: Only `Approved` will make your app available to Android TV users. Pending just means app is in queue for review. Other Android devices can still find your app which is why its available in the regular Google Play Android app store.

Comment: @MorrisonChang what about when you set internal testing, do you have to wait for it to be approved for it to show on playstore to the tester's device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have removed following feature in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false" />
```

> I have also removed following `permissions`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> //It was for Crittercism
```

As my app intended for `Android TV`, `Touchscreen emulator` and `Microphone` hardware feature does not support `Android TV`. That's why I have removed, and I was success to upload application to `Play Store` with compatible `Sony Android TV`.

For your reference, I have referred [this](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html#unsupported-features) link.

Comment: My app actually uses `RECORD_AUDIO` and is visible on my sony tv, so I think it's irrelevant