# Android Manifest for Android TV only - too few devices supported?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, android-tv

I've created an Android TV app using Unity3D and am trying to write a proper android manifest.

What I want is for my app to show up on as many Android TV devices as possible, but not on smartphones and tablets.

The documentation says:

> Declare that your app uses the Leanback user interface required by Android TV. If you are developing an app that runs on mobile (phones, wearables, tablets, etc.) as well as Android TV, set the required attribute value to false. If you set the required attribute value to true, your app will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI.

So I set leanback required to true in my manifest. 
This reduces the number of devices my app will be launched on to 40, and does not include my own test device (a Sony Bravia KDL 55W805C) for example. For Sony Bravia devices, it only seems to include 4K models, which is much more restricted than necessary.

**Am I wrong in assuming that all Android TVs use Leanback UI?

What would I have to add/remove to/from my manifest for the app to be available on as many Android TV devices as possible without including Smartphones or Tablets?**

Here's the entire manifest, in case the problem lies somewhere else:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.unity3d.player"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />

<application
    android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity 
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: How do you know the Sony Bravia is not part of that list of 40? Also you might want to refer to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37724735/1759443).

Comment: Because the list is sorted by manufacturer and there are only two Sony Bravia's on the list, but not the one I have. I have since discovered however, that the list of devices isn't accurate: another app my company has launched also only lists forty devices, but is downloadable on devices that are not on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SONY TV list in the developer console is a bit misleading, but you can basically see it as: "BRAVIA 4K - SVP-DTV15" = [All 2K/4K 2015 models]. "BRAVIA 4K GB - BRAVIA_ATV2" = [All 2K/4K 2016+ models]. See more here: https://developer.sony.com/develop/tvs/android-tv/

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I removed from Manifest permission to RECORD_AUDIO and added only these:

```
    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"/>
    <uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"/>
```

Now it supports more than 40 TV lines with Android TV.